# Showing the existence of starting two vectors satisfying the below conditions for cardinality 4,5

Tags: vectors

Given two distinct nonzero vectors $\mathbf{v}_{1}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{2}$ in 3 dimensions, define a sequence of vectors by
$$
\mathbf{v}_{n+2}=\mathbf{v}_{n} \times \mathbf{v}_{n+1}\left(\text { so } \mathbf{v}_{3}=\mathbf{v}_{1} \times \mathbf{v}_{2}, \mathbf{v}_{4}=\mathbf{v}_{2} \times \mathbf{v}_{3} \text { and so on }\right) .
$$
Let $S=\left\{\mathbf{v}_{n} \mid n=1,2, \ldots\right\}$ and $U=\left\{\frac{\mathbf{v}_{n}}{\left|\mathbf{v}_{n}\right|} \mid n=1,2, \ldots\right\}$. (Note: Here $\times$ denotes the cross product of vectors and $|\mathbf{v}|$ denotes the magnitude of the vector $\mathbf{v}$. The vector $\mathbf{0}$ with 0 magnitude, if it occurs in $S$, is counted. But in that case of course the 0 vector is not considered while listing elements of $U$.) Which of the below is/are correct ?

- (a) There exist vectors $\mathbf{v}_{\mathbf{1}}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{\mathbf{2}}$ for which the cardinality of $S$ is 2 .
- (b) There exist vectors $\mathbf{v}_{\mathbf{1}}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{2}$ for which the cardinality of $S$ is 3 .
- (c) There exist vectors $\mathbf{v}_{1}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{2}$ for which the cardinality of $S$ is 4 .
- (d) Suppose that for some $\mathbf{v}_{1}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{\mathbf{2}}$, the set $S$ is infinite. Then the set $U$ is also infinite.
- (e) There exist vectors $\mathbf{v}_{1}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{2}$ for which the cardinality of $S$ is 5

> My progress : i was able to conclude these points :

- As the vectors starting ones are non zero and distinct therefore there will always be a non zero perpendicular vector from the plane formed by those vectors.
- For a combination in which after performing one operation of cross product , next onwards giving the same intial vectors would be the intially perpendicular ones  , that is $v_1$ \perpedicular $v_2$ and most likely unit vectors only. Then i am able to see that b option is correct .
- a) option rejected  because the third vector $v_3$ is always lying perpendicular the plane of both initial vector , so all three are independent vectors .
- For the case of caridinality 4,5 i am not able to set up any examples as such and the d option i think its wrong since its possible that $v_1 \neq v_2$ and $|v_1| \neq |v_2|$ ,but still $\frac{v_1}{|v_1|} =\frac{v_2}{|v_2|}$

Answer (score 1):

There is a degenerate case where $\textbf{v}_1,\textbf{v}_2$ does not span a plane: i.e. $\textbf{v}_2=k\textbf{v}_1$ for some $k\not=0,1$. In this case, $\textbf{v}_3=\textbf{v}_4=\cdots=0$. Since $\textbf{v}_1$ and $\textbf{v}_2$ are distinct and non-zero, this makes $|S|=3$.

So, let's assume that $\textbf{v}_1,\textbf{v}_2$ span a plane. Then, you can pick an orthonormal basis $\textbf{e}_1,\textbf{e}_2,\textbf{e}_3$ with positive orientation, ie $\textbf{e}_1\times \textbf{e}_2=\textbf{e}_3$, such that $\textbf{v}_1=a\textbf{e}_1+b\textbf{e}_2$, $\textbf{v}_2=c\textbf{e}_2$ where $a,c\not=0$. This makes $\textbf{v}_3=ac\textbf{e}_3$, $\textbf{v}_4=ac^2\textbf{e}_1$, $\textbf{v}_5=a^2c^3\textbf{e}_2$, etc: for $i>1$, $\textbf{v}_i=a^{F_{i-2}}c^{F_{i-1}}\textbf{e}_j$ where $F_i$ are Fibonacci numbers ($F_i=F_{i-1}+F_{i-2}$, $F_1=F_2=1$) and $j\in\{1,2,3\}$ such that $i\equiv j\mod 3$.

If $a,c\in\{1,-1\}$, the sequence becomes cyclic with $\textbf{v}_{i+3}=\textbf{v}_i$ for $i>1$. If $b=0$, $\textbf{v}_1=a\textbf{e}_1=\textbf{v}_4=\textbf{v}_7=\cdots$, so $|S|=3$. However, if $b\not=0$, $\textbf{v}_1$ with be distinct from the remaining $v_i$, and so $|S|=4$.

If either $a$ or $c$ are distinct from $\pm1$, the $\textbf{v}_i$ will be unique from some $i$ and onward, so $S$ is an infinite set. I suspect there are many ways to prove this.
Eg, observe that the lengths $v_i=|\textbf{v}_i|>0$ satisfy $v_{i+2}=v_iv_{i+1}$ for $i>1$, and this must ultimately become increasing, decreasing, or remain alternating and converging to 1.

Thus, if $S$ is finite, $|S|\le4$.

However, $U$ remains finite even when $S$ is infinite. Eg, if $\textbf{v}_1=a\textbf{e}_1$, $\textbf{v}_2=c\textbf{v}_2$ with $a,c>1$, then $S$ is infinite, but $U=\{\textbf{e}_1,\textbf{e}_2,\textbf{e}_3\}$. In fact, $U$ will always remain finite as for $i>1$ we have $\textbf{v}_i/|\textbf{v}_i|=\textbf{e}_j$ for $j\equiv i\mod 3$. So, in the non-degenerate case, we will get $|U|=3$ if $b=0$ and $|U|=4$ if $b\not=0$.